# Java Replace $something

Tags: java, android

I have a text:
$apple,$banana

And i want to replace the $apple to $green

```
String a= "$apple,$banana";
a= a.replace("$apple","$green");
```

Its work good. I found "$green,$banana" in the 'a' variable.

But, when i use it:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("$apple","$green");

for(Map.Entry<String, String> item : map.entrySet())
{
    String from= item.getKey();
    String to= item.getValue();

    a= a.replaceAll(from,to);
}
```

Than replace not work. Result is stay $apple.

How can i replace the apple?
The $ is a special regex character. 
How can i replace it?

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

map.put("\\$apple","\\$green");